# How to get permissionId in Drive API v3?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to delete permission from the file.

In Drive API v2,

```
PermissionId permissionId = service.permissions().getIdForEmail(account).execute();
service.permissions().delete(fileId, permissionId.getId()).execute();
```

But According to document, `permissions().getIdForEmail(String email)` is removed and alternate is nothing.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration

I can't find how to get `permissionId` from specific Email address in drive API v3.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is an existing issue as stated here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4313.

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution:

```
        PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(sharedFolderId).setFields("nextPageToken, permissions(id,emailAddress)").execute();
        for (Permission p : permissions.getPermissions()) {
            if (p.getEmailAddress().equals(adresseEmail)) {
                service.permissions().delete(sharedFolderId, p.getId()).execute();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked 100%. I never used the setFields parameter but now I see what I can get from it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Two years later, but your question was the first result I found when searching for a solution. I found a workaround and I hope this will help others with the same issue. This is what I did to get the permission id:

```
this.getPermissionId = function(emailAddress) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const input = {
        q:  '"' + emailAddress + '" in writers or "' + emailAddress + '" in readers',
        fields: 'files(permissions)',
        pageSize: 1
      };

      const request = gapi.client.drive.files.list(input);

      request.execute(result => {
        if(result.error) {
          reject(result.error);
        } else if(result.files && result.files[0] && result.files[0].permissions && result.files[0].permissions[0]) {
          const permissions = result.files[0].permissions;
          let permissionId;
          permissions.forEach(permission => {
            if(permission.emailAddress == emailAddress) {
              permissionId = permission.id;
            }
          });

          if(permissionId) {
            resolve(permissionId);
          }

          else {
            reject('permissionIdUndefined');
          }
        }
      });


    })
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

a .NET version that solved my needs

```
    public static string GetPermissionIdForEmail(DriveService service, string emailAddress)
    {
        string pageToken = null;

        do
        {
            var request = service.Files.List();
            request.Q = $"'{emailAddress}' in writers or '{emailAddress}' in readers or '{emailAddress}' in owners";
            request.Spaces = "drive";
            request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, permissions)";
            request.PageToken = pageToken;

            var result = request.Execute();

            foreach (var file in result.Files.Where(f => f.Permissions != null))
            {
                var permission = file.Permissions.SingleOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.EmailAddress, emailAddress, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (permission != null)
                    return permission.Id;
            }

            pageToken = result.NextPageToken;

        } while (pageToken != null);

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this code in .NET using C#.

I hope you have already created the drive service using user's access token.

After that this code can help you to get permission ID:

```
 var permissionFile = driveService.About.Get();
 permissionFile.Fields = "*";
 var perm = permissionFile.Execute();
 permissionId = perm.User.PermissionId;
```

The `permissionId` will give you the required ID.

Answer (score 0):

I use UrlFetchApp with Google Apps Script to replace Drive API v2 and Advanced Drive Service (based on v2).

With a company domain service account, the section `getService(userEmail)` uses the library https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2 to send the request on behalf of `userEmail`.

```js
/**
 * Get user permission Id.
 *
 * @param {String} userEmail - Email address for About query.
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about
 */
function TEST_getIdForEmailV3() { getIdForEmailV3('YourEmail@CompanyDomain.com') }
function getIdForEmailV3(userEmail) {
  var service = getService(userEmail);
  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about' + '?fields=user/permissionId';
    var options = {
      'method': 'get',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers': { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() }
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var resultParsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return resultParsed.user.permissionId;
    
  } else {
    return 0;
  };
}
```