# Google drive api Permissions.Delete doesn't work

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm the owner of my google drive, I can turn on "shareable link" with below code, but when I want to set it to private (basically turn off shareable link) 
then an exception happens:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The owner of a file cannot be removed. [403] Errors [     Message[The owner of a file cannot be removed.] Location[ - ] Reason[cannotRemoveOwner] Domain[global] ]
```

I can easily set permission for the file:

```
        var permission = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.Permission();
        permission.Role = "reader";
        permission.Type = "anyone";
        var aaaa = Authentication.service.Permissions.Create(permission, fileIdAction).ExecuteAsync();
```

This is my code (doesn't work):

```
        //Get PermissionId
        var get = Authentication.service.About.Get();
        get.Fields = "*";
        var permissionId = get.Execute().User.PermissionId;

        //Delete method
        Authentication.service.Permissions.Delete(fileIdAction, permissionId).Execute();
```

I thought that permissionId might be a problem, so I tried different ways of obtaining it, however, none of them worked (Exception - about the owner). Like in this thread - [How to get permissionId in Drive API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622378/how-to-get-permissionid-in-drive-api-v3)

Any ideas of how I can set a file back to private? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the question. "The owner of a file cannot be removed."

The `permissionId` you are trying to delete is the primary ownership permission, not the sharing permission that you previously created. To get that second permissionId, either save it when you create it (it's in the response), or `get` the file's metadata and look through the `permissionIds[]`

Comment: Thank you for your response, it makes sense now. I discovered an easy fix by using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get, you can request all the info about the file in fields = *, then I saw permissionIds with two values - the first one "anyoneWithLink" and the second the long number. I have been using the second number, however, it was wrong as you stated (the number - owner). So I replaced "permissionId" with "anyoneWithLink" and it worked! Thank you for pointing it out.